# Using User(ppl finder field) to generate other fields using SharePoint Online OTB Form

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I am new to SharePoint online. I just created a SharePoint online form that user work information as fields like department, division, employee id. All of that information is in Azure AD.

My question is, where do I start to get the user info. to pull over automatically from Azure?

I figured it would be Power Automate, but I am having trouble finding documentation for step by steps on how to.

Answer (score 0):

I just have some thoughts on this issue:

1, [Get all user info. use power automate](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Help-to-extract-user-list-from-Azure-AD-to-List/td-p/1422817).

2, Export data to excel file.

3, Organize the excel file so that it conforms to the format imported into a list, and then use the from datasheet method to create a list.